# Spring 6 jdbc error - Unable to determine the correct call signature, Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am migrating my project from spring 5 to spring 6 framework and spring boot 2 to 3.
currently I am using 6.4.0.jre8 version for mssql-jdbc version

```
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
```

when I am running the application, I am getting below database error in below query.

```
    SimpleJdbcCall procedure = new SimpleJdbcCall(namedJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate())
.withProcedureName(procedureName).returningResultSet(QueryParameterConstants.P_RESULTSET, rowMapper);
                procedure.compile();
```

**error as below:**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature - no procedure/function/signature for 'getUsersRole'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.GenericCallMetaDataProvider.processProcedureColumns(GenericCallMetaDataProvider.java:365) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.GenericCallMetaDataProvider.initializeWithProcedureColumnMetaData(GenericCallMetaDataProvider.java:119) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.lambda$createMetaDataProvider$0(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:133) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:354) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:89) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
```

**second error:**

```
paramMap.put(USER_ID, userId);//As userId is Integer
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.updateNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:185) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
```

I don't want to modify the code as it is running fine with spring 5.

Is there other way to resolve these errors.

Comment: see Spring 6.x migration guide#Parameter Name Retention: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#parameter-name-retention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Exception 1:

```
Unable to determine the correct call signature - no procedure/function/signature
```

this was because my DB was not connected.

For Exception 2:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.
```

I upgraded my maven compiler plugin from 2.5.1 to 3.11.0 and added parameters tag as below:

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.11.0</version>
       <configuration>
         <parameters>true</parameters>
       </configuration>
 </plugin>
```